# Finding out what AMD Radeon Chip and installing drivers

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, graphics, radeon

I have a lenovo G500 laptop which has a label showing "AMD Radeon Graphics".
I want to find out what chip set it is and install drivers as I am unable to use graphics and am forced to use TTY mode. I have Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lspci | grep VGA` to find out the chipset of your graphics card.
AMD drivers can be installes with `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install fgrlx`.